# VS2013 configuration manager will not let me change the platform for some projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio

- VS2013 Professional
- Windows 7 64bit

I have some class libraries in my solution that are currently configured for Any CPU. However I want to change them to x64 same as my MVC project and other class libraries.

However when I go to edit them I am unable to select x64 from the "Edit Project Platform". Why is this and how do I fix this? Obviously I don't need to add x64 as it is there already.

[image]

Comment: Bump? Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution as it turned out was simple..... Instead of Edit select New and then on the following dialog make sure "Create new solution platforms" was unchecked.

[image]